# Fine tuning my query

Tags: sql-server

I'm using this to search a single table

```
Num1 num2  num3  num4  num5  num6
----------------------------------
1     2     2      5     59    100           <------grouped numbers 
1     2     3      10    20    241
1     3     1      25    22    1
2     4     4      1     3     34
2     2     3<------grouped numbers
2     2     3<------grouped numbers
3     3     4



SELECT (num1),
       (num2),
       (num3),
       (num4),
       (num5),
       (num6)
FROM numbers
WHERE (num1 = 1)
   OR (num2 = 1)


  AND (num3 = 3)
   OR (num4 = 3)


  AND (num4 = 4)
   OR (num5 = 4);
```

Example1

1, 2, 2 are grouped horizontally

Example 2

1,2,2 this combination is shown x amount of times

Example 3

1,2,2 = 1 times

2,2,3 = 2 times

It works but I have to put in all numbers manually and if 1 falls outside of num1 or num2 I miss it

I’m looking for a way to do this

1. Search all rows automatically showing number paterns of 3
2. Not having to put in the numbers manually to get the paterns
3. Show the results in a form that I can print showing all rows with these  patterns

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind your `WHERE` clause? Also, `num4` and `num5` don't exist in your sample data, where are they coming from? Dare I guess that there is also a `Num6`, `Num7`, ... `Num99`?

Comment: the sample is just to give you an idea of how the data is structured
and the where clause is the only way I could get it to work. I'm looking for a better way to do this as I'm new to sql-server

Comment: Get what to work? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: to search the table and find numbers that match

Comment: Considering you have a indeterminable amount of columns, and I still have no idea what you mean by "match" (match what?), I doubt we can help you here.

Comment: I've updated the table and what I'm looking for does this help?

Comment: Seems that you have some very serious normalization issues with your architecture which is why you are struggling. At the very least you need to share some table definition and sample data. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at all what you are trying to achieve but it looks like your table design is flawed.

Your table should be as follows

```
Num    Val
1       1
1       1
1       1
1       2
1       2
1       2
1       3
2       2
2       2
2       3
2       4
2       2
2       4
2       3
3       2
3       3
3       1
3       4
3       3
3       3
3       4
```

Your query would be something like

```
SELECT    *
FROM      numbers
WHERE     Num = Val OR Num+1 = Val -- AND etc....
```